# ubuntu: How to zip a directory in ubuntu by excluding some subdirectories from command line

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, zip

#### Added [from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20607738/1736679) as off topic, however there is no answer in here

I want to zip a directory by excluding some unwanted subdirectories. I have tried :

```
zip -r test.zip * -x 'test1/' 'test2/'
```

and

```
zip -r test.zip * -x 'test1/' -x 'test2/'
```

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

### Credits to Akhil (q.) and Naota ([ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608356/1736679).)

Try

```
zip -r test.zip * -x test1/\* test2/\*
```

The `\*` is an escaped wildcard character, which avoids path expansion by the shell prior to being passed to `zip`.

[Reference](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip) (check `--include` explanation)